# AR.js Is it possible to update the location of a gps-entity-place?

Tags: ar.js

Is it possible in AR.js to move an object placed with gps-entity-place by modifying its longitude and latitude ?

I tried to change the attribute "gps-entity-place" of the entity. It works the first time but fails after.

Answer (score 1):

## `gps-entity-place` is a read-only attribute

Instantiated objects with read-only attributes must be prepared before  displaying them:

- serve the gist over HTTPS.
- `geolocation` is not very accurate, improvements here could improve scene placement.
- `createAttribute` can be used for non-standard attributes, with hyphens like `gps-entity-place`.
- `gps.value` is used for setting values before applying them with `setAttributeNode`.
- tweak `position="[-l 0 +r] [-lower 0 +higher] [-front 0 +behind]"` of the `welcome` text, which is `-30` to the left, `0` vertical and `-150` away.
- use this [quick & dirty estimate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters) to orient test entities in world-space.

### Demo: [`markerless.html`](https://inspiredlabs.github.io/ar.js/markerless.html)

In the console the entity `a-scene` in [`markerless.html`](https://inspiredlabs.github.io/ar.js/markerless.html) shows device location AR:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://inspiredlabs.github.io/ar.js/markerless.html" />
  <!-- location based aframe v0.9.2 -->
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script><!-- debug -->
  <script>
    const log = console.log;
    window.onload = () => {
      let scene = document.querySelector('a-scene'); /* Apply to whole scene */

      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
          let gps = document.createAttribute('gps-entity-place'),
            arjs = document.createAttribute('arjs'),
            welcome = document.getElementById('welcome');

          arjs.value = 'sourceType: webcam; sourceWidth: 1280; sourceHeight: 960; trackingMethod: best; debugUIEnabled: false;';
          gps.value = `latitude: ${position.coords.latitude - 0.001}; longitude: ${position.coords.longitude + 0.001}`;
          log(gps.value);
          scene.setAttributeNode(gps); /* Apply to whole scene */
          scene.setAttributeNode(arjs);
        });
      }

    };
  </script>
</head>
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
  <a-entity id="wrapper" position="0 -8 0">

    <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9" shadow></a-box>
    <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E" shadow></a-sphere>
    <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D" shadow></a-cylinder>
    <a-plane position="0 0 -5.0" rotation="-90 0 0" width="7" height="7" color="#7BC8A4" shadow></a-plane>

    <a-text id="welcome" value="Welcome" scale="75 75 75" color="#000000" position="-30 0 -150"></a-text>
    <!-- look-at="[gps-camera]" -->

  </a-entity><!-- /wrapper -->

  <a-camera camera="fov: 60;" gps-camera rotation-reader></a-camera>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

If you're looking for different object methods to create properties, you could look into [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://sdras.github.io/object-explorer/).

References:

- [Reduced-test-cases for WebAR (GitHub Pages)](https://github.com/inspiredlabs/ar.js)
- [AR.js, Location based example (starting point)](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js#location-based-example)
- [Modified example](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/blob/master/aframe/examples/location-based/always-face-user/index.html)
- [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/inspiredlabs/pen/MWamEZV?editors=1011) will not work, nor will this: [Nicolò Carpignoli, Location Based AR.js](https://codepen.io/nicolocarpignoli/pen/MWwzyVP?editors=1111)
- [Modified example](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/blob/master/aframe/examples/location-based/always-face-user/index.html)
- [JavaScript Object Explorer](https://sdras.github.io/object-explorer/)

Comment: Uh, thank you. As I am on a totally different project now, I do not have the time to estimate your answer. I will do it asap.